# Photoshop styling looks different in CSS - and i have no idea why, any solution?

Tags: css, photoshop

Im trying to copy a style for a button from Photoshop to CSS but the result does not look the same.
i tried manually, colorzilla, "copy css style" in photoshop and even extension that do the same but the results are not alike.

this is the code i got from the style export:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #ffc243;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 11px 13px rgba(1,1,1,.28);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 11px 13px rgba(1,1,1,.28);
box-shadow: 0 11px 13px rgba(1,1,1,.28);
border: solid 4px #fff;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,.01), rgba(224,224,224,.14) 6%, rgba(224,224,224,.57) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,.09));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,.01), rgba(224,224,224,.14) 6%, rgba(224,224,224,.57) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,.09));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,.01), rgba(224,224,224,.14) 6%, rgba(224,224,224,.57) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,.09));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,.01), rgba(224,224,224,.14) 6%, rgba(224,224,224,.57) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,.09));
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.01), rgba(224,224,224,.14) 6%, rgba(224,224,224,.57) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,.09));
```

and this is the comparison between photoshop and CSS:

[image]

So any help or explanation will be very appreciated.

Thank you.

edit: just to make sure - my issue is the colors and gradient, nothing else.

Comment: CSS can't round the *inside* of a radiused corner for one!

Comment: actually, my main problem is the colors, not the corners. forgot to mention it - sorry

Comment: Well clearly whatever tool you used to get the colors was incorrect.

Comment: No browser has needed those vendor prefixed lines for many years and you can safely remove all of them.

Comment: @Rob - You're right _"No [modern] browser has needed those vendor prefixed lines for many years"_. However, some people still use old browsers.

Comment: @RobC Of those people, only one of them looks at cat videos and the other has retired to Siberia. Otherwise, the youngest browser that didn't support it was IE8. Beyond that you're talking, for example, Firefox 3.0 (now at version 72). Do not bother with vendor prefixes.

Comment: @Paulie_D yea, i know. thats why i decided to ask for help.

Comment: @RobC (your nicknames are confusing haha) those were added by the photoshop tool, the code i pasted was given by the photoshop tool after i failed to do it myself but sadly the result was the same.

Comment: Looks like a colour management issue to me

Answer (score 0):

You are using rgba code for the gradients. Try using rgb only without the opacity. The opacity is reducing the colour brightness/freshness from it.